# Pymongo query with date range

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with variable 'review_date' which is Date type. I want to get all records within a date range(start = 2019-05-17, end=2019-05-18). When I run the query getting the empty list, also tried with datetime.strptime but didn't work. Can somebody help me?

```
review_date : 2019-05-17 00:00:00.000Z
```

Here's the code:

```
@app.route('/reviews/<st_date>/<end_date>', methods=['GET'])
def index(st_date, end_date):
    collection = mongo_connection.db.reviews
    keyword_result = []
    for one_record in collection.find({'review_date': {'$gte': st_date, 
'$lt': end_date}}):
        obj_str = json_util.dumps(one_record)
        obj_dict = json.loads(obj_str, object_hook=OrderedDict)
        keyword_result.append(obj_dict)
    return keyword_result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$and` Operator,

```
collection.find({
    'review_date': {
        $and: [
            {
                $gte: ['$st_date', new Date(st_date)],
            },
            {
                $lte: ['$end_date', new Date(end_date)],
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: But I want to pass the date parameter in the URL not inside the function.

Comment: yes you can write your variables there instead of date

Comment: getting error for new Date(). I don't think python supports new and Date.

Comment: you can write python date

Comment: datetime.date(end_date)